# Is there a standard button size?

Tags: android, button

Is there a best practices size (in dip?) that buttons should be in order to be easily touchable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may find this helpful: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085. About 8mm (50 dips) should be OK.

Answer (score 39):

See https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858?hl=en which says that a touch target should — at minimum — be 48x48dp

---

**Outdated (see comments below)**: Android Design Guidelines specifically call out 48dp as the recommended minimum size for any touchable object. See "48dp Rhythm": http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: I'm confused, why isn't it 48dip instead.

Comment: `dip` and `dp` are the same thing. `dp` is just what it's referred to in code/layout because it's shorter. `dp` is still pronounced as "dip".

Comment: That link now redirects to a more generic page, that does not mention 48dp or button heights.

Answer (score 16):

Just take a look at the Android Design Guidelines for Buttons:

[image: Material Design Guideline for Button size and padding]

Source: https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style

Comment: That's visible height, not including the padding around it which is included in the touchable area. They mention this a number of times in the linked doc.

Comment: Updated link to get do that diagram:  [Buttons- Material Design- Spec](https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#specs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/light_blue" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#215368" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" 
            android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

this for round button, make sure the width and height is same.

[image]